# Uso de ventana para entrada de datos con Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

lo primero disculpad si la pregunta es muy tonta o muy básica, mis conocimientos de programación no llegan mucho más allá y no he encontrado nada en el buscador que me haya resuelto la duda.

La cosa es que quiero que un programa en un momento determinado mediante una llamada a una función abra una ventana para preguntar al usuario/a unos datos (en el caso real una fecha) y que llegado el momento se pulse el botón aceptar y la información capturada se devuelva al programa principal (que se estará ejecutando en otra ventana).

La cosa es que no sé cómo hacer ese retorno de los datos. Pongo un código de ejemplo:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

def ventanaCapturaDatos():
    def devolverDatos():
        textoCaja=entryTexto.get()
        print(textoCaja)
        texto.set(textoCaja)
        return(textoCaja)


    root=Tk()
    root.title("Entrada de datos")

    #FRAME DE ENTRADA DE DATOS

    miFrame=Frame(root)
    miFrame.pack()

    texto=StringVar()


    #ENTRY 

    entryTexto=Entry(miFrame, justify=CENTER ,textvariable=texto)
    entryTexto.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)


    #BOTÓN ACEPTAR

    botonAceptar=Button(miFrame, text="Aceptar", command=lambda:devolverDatos())
    botonAceptar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e", padx=5, pady=5)

    root.mainloop()




print("Llamamos a la ventana de entrada de datos")

texto=ventanaCapturaDatos()

print("El texto que has introducido es:")
print(texto)
```

Más o menos entiendo que el problema es que la función ventanaCapturaDatos no llega a hacer su return, pero no sé cómo lo tengo que hacer, si dentro de las acciones que se dan al pulsar el botón o si hay alguna manera de hacerlo desde dentro de la función devolverDatos.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Vale, ya lo he solucionado, lo pongo por si le vale a alguien.

Me ha funcionado haciendo el return de la función ventanaCapturaDatos después del mainloop, este return se ejecutará una vez la función devolver datos cierre el mainloop con el método destroy.

En el ejemplo anterior:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


def ventanaCapturaDatos():

    def devolverDatos():
        textoCaja=entryTexto.get()
        texto.set(textoCaja)
        root.destroy()


    root=Tk()
    root.title("Entrada de datos")

    #FRAME DE ENTRADA DE DATOS

    miFrame=Frame(root)
    miFrame.pack()

    texto=StringVar()


    #ENTRY 

    entryTexto=Entry(miFrame, justify=CENTER ,textvariable=texto)
    entryTexto.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)


    #BOTÓN ACEPTAR

    botonAceptar=Button(miFrame, text="Aceptar", command=lambda:devolverDatos())
    botonAceptar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e", padx=5, pady=5)

    root.mainloop()

    return texto.get()




print("Llamamos a la ventana de entrada de datos")

texto=ventanaCapturaDatos()

print("El texto que has introducido es:")
print(texto)
```

Supongo que no es la manera más ortodoxa de hacerlo pero para lo que lo necesito creo que funcionará.